# How to use groupby with array elements in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running a groupBy operation on a dataframe in Pyspark and I need to groupby a list which may be by one or two features.. How can I execute this?

```
 record_fields = [['record_edu_desc'], ['record_construction_desc'],['record_cost_grp'],['record_bsmnt_typ_grp_desc'], ['record_shape_desc'],
['record_sqft_dec_grp', 'record_renter_grp_c_flag'],['record_home_age'],
['record_home_age_grp','record_home_age_missing']]


for field in record_fields: 
    df_group = df.groupBy('year', 'area', 'state', 'code', field).sum('net_contributions')
    ### df write to csv operation
```

My first thought was to create a list of lists and pass it to the groupby operation, but I get the following error:

> TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column:
>   ['record_edu_desc'] of type . For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.

How do I make this work?   I'm open to other ways I could do this.

Comment: Do you want to groupBy all the column names in `record_fields`  field along with state, year, code etc.. ?

Comment: Yes but with a loop with only a single element at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (note that `*` [asterisk] before `field`):

```
for field in record_fields: 
    df_group = df.groupBy('year', 'area', 'state', 'code', *field).sum('net_contributions')
```

Also take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters) to know more about asterisk in python.